# unexpected error php

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo el siguiente error en mi formulario, se que me falta algo pero no se donde. miren:

```html
<?php if(Session::getUID()!=""):?>
   <?php
   $u=null;
   if(Session::getUID()!=""){
     $u = PacientData::getById(Session::getUID());
     $user = $u->name." ".$u->lastname." ".$u->username." ".$u->email;
     ?>
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
   <th>Nombre completo</th>
   <th>Usuario</th>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th>Activo</th>
   <th></th>
   </thead>
   <?php
   foreach($users as $user){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $user->name." ".$user->lastname; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->username; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->email; ?></td>
    <td>
     <?php if($user->is_active):?>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
    </td>
    <td style="width:150px;"><a href="index.php?view=editpacient&id=<?php echo $user->id;?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Editar</a>
    </tr>
    <?php

   endif;

  }

  ?>

 </div>
</div>
```

donde podria estar el fallo?

Comment: Cual es el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que hay un `if` que no estás cerrando, puede que sea este:

```
                <?php if($user->is_active):?>
```

por lo que se alcanza a entender en la lógica de tu programa.

Tienes un código bastante confuso, por dos motivos principales:

- mezclas dos estilos de `if` lo cual no es recomendable
- demasiadas aperturas/cierres de bloques PHP para combinar con HTML, es lícito, pero produce un código horrible. Recomiendo que concatenes, usando un solo bloque PHP.

Propongo esto, apreciarás la diferencia en cuanto a claridad:

```
<?php 
    if(Session::getUID()!="") {
            $u=null;
            if(Session::getUID()!=""){
              $u = PacientData::getById(Session::getUID());
              $user = "$u->name $u->lastname $u->username $u->email";
              $html="<table class=\"table table-bordered table-hover\">";
              /* Empezamos a concatenar... NÓTESE el uso de .= */
              $html.="<thead>
              <th>Nombre completo</th>
              <th>Usuario</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Activo</th>
              <th></th>
              </thead>";
                 foreach($users as $user){
                    $html.="<tr>";
                    $html.="<td>$user->name $user->lastname </td>";
                    $html.="<td>$user->username</td>";
                    $html.="<td>$user->email</td>";
                    $statusActive=( $user->is_active ) ? "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></i>" : "";
                    $html.="<td>$statusActive</td>";
                    $url="index.php?view=editpacient&id=$user->id";
                    $lastCell="<td style=\"width:150px;\"><a href=\"$url\" class=\"btn btn-warning btn-xs\">Editar</a>";
                    $html.="<td>$lastCell</td>";
                    $html.="</tr>";             
                }
            }
    }
    echo $html;
    /*
        *Ojo a esto, dejo los div fuera de la variable $html
        *porque no sé de dónde vienen, pero hace pensar que 
        *es necesario mejorar aún la lógica de tu programa
        *construyendo todo  en la misma variable y haciendo echo al final
    */
    echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Me he valido de otras técnicas, como el uso de operadores ternarios. Verás que he preferido construir aparte la url del enlace, es una opción personal (no me gusta escribir líneas de código interminables).

Hay otra prácticas no recomendadas en tu código, como el hecho de aplicar estilos directamente, actualmente se recomienda usar clases y manejar los estilos vía CSS.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio de mucho